# Can not open a folder in IntelliJ, how to solve it?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, directory

I made a change on my local and pushed it to GitHub. Right after this, the problem started.

I am trying to open a folder using IntelliJ Idea (in the image you can see: **Idea Projects > Java101** folder) but IntelliJ navigates me to another folder and opens it (**Idea Projects > GIT KULLANIMI**).

I want to revert my changes (if it is the solution) but as far as I understand, since I committed and pushed it, it is not possible.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

[Related screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Efq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've solved the problem. I've changed (you can delete as well) the location of the related folder and then cloned the one on Github. So it works now!

PS: Not deleting this post in case anyone has the same issue in the future.